# refactor if to takeIf and return "return" without label kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to write more idiomatic Kotlin code and I am stuck with the best way to refactor this if condition. Basically when the condition if true (fragment is  GenericActionsBottomSheetDialog instance in a list of Fragments) I return the funcion itself.

Here is what I had and how I refactored it. Is there better way to achieve it? After my refactoring it get worse:

Before refactor:

```
        supportFragmentManager.fragments.iterator().forEach {
            if (it is GenericActionsBottomSheetDialog)
                return
```

After refactor:

```
        supportFragmentManager.fragments.iterator().forEach { it ->
            it.apply {
            takeIf { it is GenericActionsBottomSheetDialog }?.apply { return }}}
```

Comment: The first version looks much better indeed. What is the rest of the `forEach` block?

Comment: Three is none .

Comment: You’re returning from the outer function early if any one of the fragments meets the condition? I think we need to see more context, maybe the whole function that includes this code, to be able to understand exactly what you’re doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this `forEach` is the only thing in your current function (which it should IMO), you could get rid of the non-local return by using `takeWhile` instead:

```kotlin
supportFragmentManager.fragments
    .takeWhile { it !is GenericActionsBottomSheetDialog }
    .forEach {
         // do stuff 
    }
```

/!\ be careful that this changes semantics if there is other stuff after the `forEach` in the same function declared with `fun`.

If you expect many fragments in the list, you could also use `asSequence()` before `takeWhile` so you don't create an intermediate list.

Comment: after for-each loop I have block of code responsible for fragment display, this code has NOT to be executed if the element in list is GenericSheetDialog, that is why I execute non local return, in order to block rest of the code. Will it work the same with takeWhile?

Comment: It wouldn't work the same with `takeWhile`, hence my warning. You can use the `any` function as suggested by @gidds, to just perform the return, and then separate the code used to process items

Answer (score 2):

This is an opinion based question, and answers cannot be any different.

That being said: there is nothing wrong with `if` clauses. From what I can see from your current question, I'd leave it with an `if`.

Now, if you really do not want to use it, filter elements that are not of type `GenericActionsBottomSheetDialog` and apply whatever function you want on them (the part that is in your `else` clause, which we do not see).

**EDIT:**

In case you only want to check if the object of the `GenericActionsBottomSheetDialog` exists in the collection, you can perhaps do it like this:

```kotlin
val dialogExists = supportFragmentManager.fragments
    .firstOrNull { it is GenericActionsBottomSheetDialog} != null

if (dialogExists) {
    return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility, which separates the decision from the action:

```
if (supportFragmentManager.fragments.any{ it is GenericActionsBottomSheetDialog })
    return
```

I think this approach makes the intent clearest. (It's also about the most efficient.)

[`any()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html) simply checks each item in turn, stopping when it finds a match (or when it reaches the end of the list). Kotlin has many functions like this (inspired by functional programming languages) that use lambdas to operate on lists and other structures. They tend to be named for *what* they do, rather than *how* they do it — which makes code using them both short and easy to read. (You should be writing code for people to read, as much as for computers to execute!)

For completeness, here's another approach, which uses [`filterIsInstance()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-is-instance.html):

```
if (supportFragmentManager.fragments
        .filterIsInstance<GenericActionsBottomSheetDialog>)
        .isNotEmpty())
    return
```

There are bound to be many other ways. But I agree with the commenter that your ‘refactored’ approach, while using many more Kotlin functions, has little else to recommend it!

Answer (score 1):

@gidds solution is IMO the most idiomatic one:

```
if (supportFragmentManager.fragments
   .any { it is GenericActionsBottomSheetDialog }) return
```

I would like to add this solution eliminating the if:

```
supportFragmentManager.fragments
   .firstOrNull { it is GenericActionsBottomSheetDialog } 
   ?.run { return }
```

It's a matter of taste which one you pick, I prefer the first one.

I was wondering why you use the iterator? You could simply do:

```
supportFragmentManager.fragments.forEach {
```